# как сделать так, чтобы помещались все слова в Inline кнопку telebot

Tags: python, telebot

[image: здесь видно, как второе слово после "Бакалавриат" не помещается]

```
# добавил кнопки о поступлении
markup_arrive = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
markup_arrive1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Бакалавриат/cпециалитет",
                                            url="google.com",
                                            callback_data="bachelor ")
```

Comment: Разместить кнопки вертикально? А вы как себе представляете это решение?

Comment: @gil9red, нет, не вертикально))) либо, текст кнопки поместился во всю ее длину, или слова ( бакалавриат и специалитет ) разместились друг под другом

Comment: первый ряд одна кнопка, второй ряд две кнопки. Если заморочится, то типа бегущей строки в кнопке

Comment: Есть еще один креативный подход, как запутать пользователя: это в тексте описать: 1) - ; 2) - ; 3) - ; ... И в кнопочках поставить только 1, 2, 3 :D

В том числе можно сделать, что-то по типу Бакалавриат*

А в тексте:
* - в том числе специалитет.

Только учтите, что * может плохо восприниматься parse-mode, если он имеется

Comment: всем спасибо, проблема решена))